# Erro: O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, processo

> Win32Exception (0x80004005): 
>               O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado em System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Ao tentar executar um programa recém publicado me deparei com este erro, que se refere a uma aplicação externa ao meu aplicativo, chamada pelo trecho de código que menciono a seguir:

```
private void CreatePorts(string command, bool ports)   
{            
   Process p = new Process();        

   p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (Application.StartupPath + @"\com0com");
   p.StartInfo.FileName = @"setupc.exe";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   p.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
   p.StartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
   p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;                                                
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + command;
   p.Start();
}
```

É certo de que o endereço passado para o parâmetro `WorkingDirectory` está correto e de que o arquivo mencionado no parâmetro `FileName` existe, por isso não entendo o que há de errado.

Comment: Verificando se o arquivo existe e se você tem permissão para executá-lo?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo também não se trata de permissão, configurei para que ele abrisse sempre como administrador. O arquivo existe e tem permissões.

Comment: Mas onde em seu código você está verificando isso?

Comment: Por se tratar de aplicações executáveis externas, acreditei que não precisaria verificar isso internamente, uma vez que configurei cada aplicação individualmente. Mas eu verifico se a minha aplicação principal foi aberta com permissões de administrador, no caso.

Comment: E o `Application.StartupPath`, você verificou se o caminho dele está retornando o que você espera? não está iniciando em dentro da `release` ou `debug`, onde você não tem o subdiretório `com0com`?

Comment: Verifiquei sim. Eu apenas o inicio após publica-lo. Tenho total certeza do diretório em que ele está sendo executado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução foi a criação de uma variável de ambiente para o processo que estive tentando executar. No meu caso: `C:\Program Files (x86)\com0com`

<kbd>Sistema</kbd>  → <kbd>Config. Avançadas do Sistema</kbd>  → <kbd>Variaveis de Ambiente</kbd> → <kbd>Adicionar no path a variável em questão</kbd>